# Redis error when running on Docker "Failed opening the RDB file dump.rdb"

Tags: docker, redis

I run redis on docker very well, but 2-3 hours after I view the log, I get the below error as shown

I also have the additional problem that when I SET a value that lasts for 12 hours using the SETEX command, the value disappears on its own, and lasts only 5 - 10 minutes

I don't know what the cause is

[Picture Redis Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTqBj.png)

Answer (score 0):

After trying all kinds of Redis Mods, and official Redis on Docker, the error still doesn't go away

In the end, I had to change servers. I use Vultr, I had to create a new server and that error went away. The code has no errors, something goes wrong on the server hardware

I'm more comfortable using Linode